# Is it possible to get confidence intervals in metafor for the R^2 value?

Tags: r

So I am trying to run a meta-analysis with correlations. I can run the code fine. But was wondering if it is then possible to get a confidence interval around the R2 value.

```
boot.func <- function(data.boot) {

res <- try(rma(yi, vi, data=data.boot), silent=TRUE)

if (is.element("try-error", class(res))) {
NA
} else {
c(coef(res), vcov(res), res$tau2, res$se.tau2^2)
}

}

data.gen <- function(dat, mle) {
 data.frame(yi=rnorm(nrow(dat), mle$mu, sqrt(mle$tau2 + dat$vi)), vi=dat$vi)
}

set.seed(8781328)
res.boot <- boot(dat, boot.func, R=100, sim="parametric", ran.gen=data.gen, 
mle=list(mu=coef(res), tau2=res$R2))
res.boot

boot.ci(res.boot, type=c("norm", "basic", "stud", "perc"), index=3:4)
```

I have tried this code, but it seems to give very different values. Furthermore, it seems to be able to give studentized values, which as far as I'm aware should not be possible as there is no no variance estimate for R2

`res = rma.uni(dat$yi, dat$vi, mods = ~ dat$Age)`

Answer (score 2):

What ever statistic you are trying to compute, bootstrapping will provide you within confidence intervals.  Namely bootstrapping will give you a number of estimates of the value of your statistic.  Bin all those numbers.  The values given by the '2.5%' and '97.5%' bins are the boundaries of your 95% confidence interval.  In one of his books, Efron says,  you should bootstrap at least 2500 times in order to get reliable confidence intervals.